# How to query similar records in SQLite database from Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

Let's say an SQLite database column contains the following value:
`U Walther-Schreiber-Platz`

Using a query I'd like to find this record, or any similar records, if the user searches for the following strings:

- `walther schreiber`
- `u walther`
- `walther-schreiber platz`
- [Any other similar strings]

However I cannot figure out any query which would do that. Especially if the user does not enter the `-` character.

Example:
`select * from myTable where value like '%walther schreiber%';` would not return the result because of the missing `-`.

Thanks,
Robert

Comment: replace all of the spaces' ' with percents '%', so like: '%walther%schreiber% and lower or upper both sides of the where clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as I said in my comment, I think you can have a query along the lines of:

```
select * from myTable where LOWER(value) like <SearchValue>
```

I'm assuming you're collecting the `<SearchValue>` from the user programmatically, so would be able to do the following: `<SearchValue>` would need to be:  The user's search string, appropriately cleansed to avoid [SQL injection attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain), converted to lower case, with all of the spaces converted to '%', so that they match zero or more characters...

So you would have (for example):

```
select * from myTable where LOWER(value) like '%walther%schreiber%'
select * from myTable where LOWER(value) like '%walther-schreiber%platz%'
```

etc...  however, this does assume that the word order is the same, which in your examples it is...

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I was looking for. Couldn't think of it though it looks somewhat logical :-)